# How to add permission for a google apps script url

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, google-apps-script, google-sheets, credentials

Long story short, doing a project that I need access to a google spreadsheet. The company has a lot of bureaucracy about allowing staff to create credentials(still ongoing the request). I tried to find a workaround to it using google apps script each I was managing just for a sheet inside a spreadsheet, @Cooper helped me out to sort this problem. I deployed the a webapp out of the script below that export all the data into the spreadsheet to a json format in an url link.
Once I try to import it with python in VSCode I have a message saying that the email needs match. I have been reading the google documentation to find something to add the email as credential without have an API and I could not so far.
So I would like to add the email as the credential to access the data I have export to the link that way I will be able to fetch the data into a dataframe and work from there.

```
function getAllData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let obj = {}
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    obj[sh.getName()] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  })
  return ContentService.creatTextOutput(JSON.stringify(obj))
  .setMimeType(Content.Service.MimeType.JSON)
}
```

I have not found anything with google/python that I can't fetch the url without the API. For now I tried with urllib as below:

```
import urllib.request
import json

sheetURL = 'link to the sheet'

res = urllib.request.urlopen(sheetURL)
jsonData = res.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: so what's your python code?

Comment: @EdoAkse I have append the code into the question. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: do you have access to this sheet with your account?

Comment: @EdoAkse yes I do and few others in the company, I can share the privileges with anyone within the company.

Comment: so I know 2 options (which are not a solution to the exact problem you're having). One is to create a simple python script to get access tokens with the correct scopes to access the sheet from python code directly (without gScript) and the other would be to add a serviceaccount as a reader/writer/whatever and access the contents directly with that account. I think the latter would be better. Note that I couldn't get your script to work by simply copying/pasting it in the gScripts editor...

Comment: @EdoAkse serviceaccount as read would do it. Could you give some guidance on that one, please? Such as a simple example if possible? Thanks for your kind help so far.

Comment: [Create SA](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) and the give that read/write access on the gSheet (like a normal user) → use [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/). Or get an accesstoken for your personal account using fe [this documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/oauth-installed.html) and then use gspread with it

Comment: for gspread there's actually nice docs [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account) EDIT use the specific json file location when instantiating the gspread object, don't put random SA json files in weird locations as it suggests in that doc

Comment: @EdoAkse yeah I just tried it now, I can not create a credential that is my main issue. Reason why I tried the google script

Comment: are you able to create a serviceaccount? It's not the same as a credentials object. See [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating)